# Open an activity without declaring it in the manifest file in ANDROID?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to open an Activity without declaring it in a manifest file.
I don't know if it is possible or not.
What I actually want is to dynamically open an Activity from my program using Intents.
Can anyone help me if it is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Not possible. Although I am unsure what you mean "dynamically open an activity".

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Under Class Overview it states "To be of use with Context.startActivity(), all activity classes must have a corresponding  declaration in their package's AndroidManifest.xml"

You can have an Activity in your package and not define it in the manifest, however you would not be able to start it successfully.

Comment: Oh So there is no way to start an activity dynamically.Anyway thanks for the help -> Matt M.

Comment: Dynamically I meant like this ....I have a list of packagenames and activity names. These are in a list view. I want to open each activity by clicking on the item in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'Dynamic' activity start is actually the normal way of starting an activity (as you have said in a comment to the answer of Matt M). Though you **HAVE** to add the Activities in manifest as *Matt M* said. In list view, clicking an activity will call a function that will start respective activity with startActivity() function.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this very long, but since the Instrumentation class uses the IActivityTaskManager, which is a class of the internal API located at com.android.server.wm, that is not in the Activity classloader, I solved this by another method:

> Using a subclass

I just made an Gist, with sample code.

[GIST](https://gist.github.com/ValentinAhrend/374c54c04470d4d012d3607b595893c6)