# Dynamically create an activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to create an activity dynamically. Something like:

```
Activity a = new Activity();
```

Is it possible ? Do I need a special permission ? Or is it simply not possible ?

The error I get: I don't get any exception but the program stops when I try to use this instruction.

Comment: You can do it, but it's not really a normal thing to do.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Casey I'm programming a multiple stack framework, and I cannot use the standard android framework with one class for each activity. I need to program everything dynamically.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534069/open-an-activity-without-declaring-it-in-the-manifest-file-in-android).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't instantiate an Activity if it's not in the Manifest, so you can't create one dynamically.

Answer (score 5):

You can't create Activities at runtime so what you can do is create Layouts at runtime and change the Layout according to the event...

Here you are going to use Layout change instead of starting a new Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of multiple activities you can Fragments.
You can use the same Layouts with Fragments and you can instantiate them dynamically and remove. In this way you can create a stack based application.

Answer (score -2):

are you trying to start an activity?

use context.startActivity(intent);  where the intent defines what activity you want to start.