# How to create Activity dynamically

Tags: android

I have some idea for my app. But I don't know how to do.
Basic, we create activity then load it, or call some another Activity from buttom...
My idea is:
We have a ListView, can add, remove item. So everytime we add a item, we add a Activity,too.
How many items in listview so activity is many,too.
Ho to do that?

Comment: learn some basics about listview and adapter, removing and adding element to listview can be done in one activity!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can not create **Activity dynamically** but you can assign already exist activity to number of items in listview.

You can also make your activity to behave differently according to different values but all is depends on your requirement and your logical implementation.

Make sure that all your Activity is listed in Manifest. **Do remember**.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313799/582571) & [this](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5b476d648da729d0) links mentioning the same.