# creating activities dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-activity

How does android register an activity from the android manifest file so that it appears in package manager. I do understand that this is done at the time of app installation. Is there a way to tweak the android source to create an API to dynamically create and register activities ?

Comment: Just look at this question posted on 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313610/dynamically-create-an-activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does android register an activity from the android manifest file

you should have look [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) to get All the Information about how Android Menifest file Works and how you can register your activity in it.

> Is there a way to tweak the android source to create an API to
>   dynamically create and register activities ?

AFAIK you can not able to Create Dynamic Activity as it will not be defined in Android Menifest file. you must have to defined it to Manifest file to create an instance of that Activity to Use it in your Code.

Comment: Yes, I do agree that activity can be registered only through android manifest file. But android always converts xml file into java code which actually gets executed. Eg: All resource xml files are mapped to R.java. Similarly, there must be some java code which is generated from Android manifest file. If I can tweak this code, may be it is possible to dynamically register activities.

Comment: @NightFury actually, AndroidManifest is application interface that is registered inside system after application installed. After you create an intent, system searches components that support it and sends intent to them. So it is impossible to modify this interface on runtime.

Comment: @NightFury: you can also upvote this Answer if it some how helps you.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant create an activity dynamically because there is no API to modify content on manifest file dynamically. How ever you can change the layout of your activity according to your need...

Answer (score 0):

no way to do this via code. you should register activity in manifest.

Create an activity which contains fragment. Later you can create several instances of this activity and load different fragments in runtime with different content and logic.