# creating a number of activity in android based the user input?

Tags: java, android, layout, android-activity

I am working with a basic game application where I need to create `x` no of activity based on the users input `x`. Each activity should have an edit text and the final activity should display all values in a text view. Is it possible?

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392906/creating-activities-dynamically-in-android

Comment: No you should never create x numbers of Activities based on user input! Every activity should have a clearly defined and unique purpose. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: I have a feeling you really don't need so many activities. Why not reuse the same activity and pass the old activities edittext value and number of times activity opened to the new activity with intent?

Comment: You can use one activity class and start it x times